# Android and HttpGet time out response chance

Tags: android, timeout, http-get

I have an instance of `HttpGet`, and I've set timeouts in `HttpConnectionParams`. My connection and request probably won't time out but they might and I'd like the chance to respond to this and some how inform the user of this event.

How/Where can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A connection timeout would cause an `ConnectTimeoutException`, catch that and display a message. If you don't need to do anything specific, catching `IOException` might be good enough.

Comment: Ah yes - because it extends `IOException`. Thanks.